# Как реализовать требование к уникальности значения столбца в PosgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть два столбца, один из них это некий идентификатор (НЕ primary key - может дублироваться),
другой - это boolean, который указывает, какой из одинаковых идентификаторов хранит актуальные данные в своей строке.

То есть как-то так:

```
1|124|true
2|124|false
3|124|false
4|541|true
5|138|true
```

Как описать в схеме таблицы, что на любое количество равных идентификаторов, может быть только одно значение `true` (актуальный), а остальные - только `false`(неактуальный)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этой задачи нужен частичный индекс, который в postgresql может быть уникальным и таким образом гарантировать уникальность значений только для части таблицы:

```
create unique index on tablename (fieldname) where some_immutable_condition
```

Если предположить что ваше булево поле названо `is_active`, а идентификатор `key_id`, то:

```
create unique index on tablename (key_id) where is_active
```

---

Другая возможность делать странные вещи с ограничениями на строки в таблице - [`Exclusion Constraints`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) (им подвластно, например, сделать проверку что даты бронирования номера отеля не пересекаются между собой). А вот `check constraints` такой фокус сделать не дадут, они могут проверять только свою собственную строку.